# Selenium throws a "not clickable at point" error but still clicks it and proceedes with the code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Sooo I am scraping https://www.fragrantica.com/search/  and in order to make it easier to scrape what I need I apply the filters they have at their page in this order : I pick an industry > gender > Country > year.
Now my issue is this:
When it is looping through the filters it throws this error :

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" value="Fragrances"> is not clickable at point (185, 702). Other element would receive the click: <ins id="aswift_5_anchor" style="border: none !important; height: 124px !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; position: relative !important; visibility: visible !important; background-color: transparent !important; display: block !important; inset: auto !important; clear: none !important; float: none !important; max-height: none !important; max-width: none !important; opacity: 1 !important; overflow: visible !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; z-index: auto !important;">...</ins>
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
```

But when I check the page it shows that it already clicked it and went through to click on gender then stops for some reason.
Here is proof:

[image]

and also gender is clicked:

[image]

So what is the issue exactly ?
Here is my function:

```
def filter():
    for industry in Industry_dict.values():
        for gender in Gender_dict.values():
            for country in Country_dict.values():
                for year in range(1920, 2023):
                    industry_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, industry)))
                    industry_selected.click()

                    time.sleep(2)

                    gender_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, gender)))
                    gender_selected.click()

                    time.sleep(2)

                    try:
                        country_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, country)))
                        country_selected.click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                    except:
                        break
                         
                    start = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, start_year_xpath)))
                    start.click()
                    start.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(2)

                    end = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, end_year_xpath)))
                    end.click()
                    end.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(2) 

                    clear  = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, clear_filters_button)))
                    clear.click()
```

P.S : I am yet to scrape whatever pops after the filtering because I wanted filtering to be working well then continue ~

Comment: try/catch the call and you'll be able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of using the .click() I just replaced it with driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", "your web element"). So the updated code is :

```
def filter():
    for industry in Industry_dict.values():
        for gender in Gender_dict.values():
            for country in Country_dict.values():
                for year in range(1920, 2023):
                    
                    industry_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, industry)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", industry_selected)
                    time.sleep(2)

                    gender_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, gender)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", gender_selected)
                    time.sleep(2)
                
                    country_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, country)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", country_selected)
                    time.sleep(2)
                         
                    start = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, start_year_xpath)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", start)
                    start.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(2)

                    end = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, end_year_xpath)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", end)
                    end.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(2) 

                    clear  = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, clear_filters_button)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clear)
```